# While loops in kotlin

Tags: while-loop, kotlin, infinite-loop

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var x = 9
    while (x>=0){
        println(x)
        x++
    }
}
```

If i compile this code, it will print out an infinite number of iteration of the loop.

Any way to set a limit of iteration there ?

Comment: One way is to set an appropriate condition for the while.

Comment: Note that, due to integer overflow, the loop won't really be infinite.

Comment: Or you could count the iterations manually and break the loop when you exceed allowed number.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i still dont know of to manually count the iterations xD but thx, ill keep that in mind ^^

Comment: @mathieu: it's very simple: have a separate counter variable which you increment every iteration.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you mean with break and continue functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
while (x>=0){
```

to

```
while (x<100){
```

It will give you all number from `9` to `99`. Don't hesitate to change the condition based on your requirement.

Just put a valid one, which stops.

Comment: ok thx a lot i actualy wrote

while (x<=1000)

but yeah thx for the help. If i had put a more deep thinking i wouldnt have to bother you guys, sry xD

Comment: Consider accepting the answer for future reference.

Comment: i will, i just have to wait a bit ^^.